# service restart doesn't happen when using cron

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a script that I call from a cron job. The script is

```
#!/bin/bash

python /home/ubuntu/gateway-haproxy-config.py | tee /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg.new
DIFF=$(diff /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg.new)

if [ "$DIFF" != "" ]
then
    mv /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg.new /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
    service haproxy restart
else
    echo "unmodified"
fi
```

The script works exactly as expected when I run it from a shell prompt.

I installed it as a cron job as follows (for root using `sudo crontab -e`):

```
* * * * * cd /home/ubuntu && ./gateway-config-cron
```

When the cron runs, the script successfully writes a new configuration file, does the diff and even replaces the old one with the new one when the diff is not empty.

The `service haproxy restart` never happens when running as a cron job. I am forced to manually restart the service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might have been a path related problem I was able to make it work as expected by providing the full path to `service`.

```
#!/bin/bash

python /home/ubuntu/gateway-haproxy-config.py | tee /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg.new
DIFF=$(diff /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg.new)

if [ "$DIFF" != "" ]
then
    mv /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg.new /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
    /usr/sbin/service haproxy restart
else
    echo "unmodified"
fi
```